# RTT Variation in NS3

Tags: networking, simulation, ns-3

How does RTT vary in ns3 ?

I have a point to point link in which the delay and bandwidth parameters I have given, the RTT must be twice of the delay. But RTT varies , where is it changing ? How is it changing ?

Answer (score 0):

It can vary because of to NetDevices's buffering , TCP's efficiency, ACKs failure and many more,  even for a P2P link with configured delay and bandwidth parameters.